# Migrating old page to new site---data that was appearing is not coming back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I'm taking a pre-existing project and migrating it to a new site. Axios is being used to fetch the data and show it throughout the project.

This project (that I did not work on) utilizes a lot of promises and async functions and is pointed to a url that points to something obsolete.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- None of the data is loading on my page...*however*, I can see the JSON data by following the site links
- This application was working on the old site (and all of the data was present)---hence, I don't think this is an axios issue (I could be wrong)
- I don't know how to work with the urls nested under the async function (see code below)

#### index.js:

```
// various imports

const { globalData, myUser } = await globalInitProm;
```

Going into `globalInitProm` leads to:

#### global.js:

```
export default globalInitPromise();
```

Going into `globalInitPromise();` leads to:

```
// global.js
async function globalInitPromise() {
  const myObj = await loadMYProperties();
  const token = await permissionToCallMYAPI(myObj.hsHost);
  const myUser = new MYUser(myObj, token);
```

Here's where `hsHost` originates from:

```
// helper.js

import axios from "axios";

const myObj = {};

export async function loadMYProperties(obj) {
  myObj.spUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
  myObj.hsHost = "https://handshake.mysite.com"; 
  myObj.multivaluePeoplePicker = true;
  if (obj) {
    for (i in obj) {
      myObj[i] = obj[i];
    }
  }

loadPeoplePickerScripts();

  await loadCurrentUser();

  return myObj;

}
```

Handshake is the software that we're migrating away from. If I point `myObj.hsHost` to the new url that we're working with, nothing changes.

Comment: What does not coming back mean? There have to be some details in the developer console, look at the network tab. Are calls actually made? What is the response? Timeout? Error? Non HTTP 200 code?